# java web service (jersey) on tomcat only works when running from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, rest, jersey, tomcat7

I developed few web services using Eclipse and Jersey and Tomcat 7 as the server.

When running the project from Eclipse, everything works fine. However, when deploying the project WAR file directly to Tomcat (using it's manager), I'm getting 404 error when calling the service.

My WEB-INF\lib directory contains all jersey libs.

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>myApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.myapp.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myApp REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I believe I'm missing something on the Tomat configuration, but have no idea...

Any idea?

Ahanks,
Assaf

Comment: what does your `web.xml` look like?

Comment: What does the Tomcat log say?

Comment: And what URL are you calling to test the service?

Answer (score 0):

ok...

problem solved by taking the following two actions:

**a.** configuring the following entries of \tomcat\conf\server.xml, replacing the "localhost" attribute with the actual server name:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost"> 
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

**b.** taking care of windows firewall, to allow inbound http:8080. I'm feeling a bit embarrassed - for some reason I thought setting the Amazon security rules was enough (-:

Thanks for your attention.

Assaf

Answer (score 0):

Try This one ...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.hrms.admin.jersey.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Visit This one : [Jersey](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)